# How to perform webkit transform scaling

Tags: css, hover, webkit, transform

I'm attempting to edit this code below.

```
#snaps .content-area .snap-item {
    width: 350px;
    height: 215px;
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    background-color: #fff;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 20px 50px;
    -webkit-transition: all .15s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .15s linear;
    -o-transition: all .15s linear;
    transition: all .15s linear;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -ms-border-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#snaps .content-area .snap-item:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
}
```

It creates a zoom in function but in fact I would like to do the opposite or have options for what i can do on a hover state. I've looked but can't seem to find anything definitive so hopefully some knowledgeable folks here can help out!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Uuhhh, changing `scale` to anything lower than `1` should make it zoom out (the opposite). Did you even read up on CSS?

Comment: No need to be snarky @Rvervuurt, obviously I didn't know what I was looking for hence my post. I'm still learning!!

Comment: If you can't read CSS and can't understand you can change the zoom by changing `1.1` to another value, you are simply skipping some very important steps and you should learn those first.

Comment: As stated above 'I am still learning'.

Comment: But you are skipping some important steps when you don't understand what value-changes do. It might be better to go back to basic and learn about properties and values, before working with CSS like the above and asking a question that can be solved with a bit of self-study.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the `scale` in the `:hover`-part to anything less than 1 should make it do the opposite of what it is doing when using `1.1`.

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4pejLocL/)

CSS I edited:

```
#snap-item:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(.8, .8);
    -moz-transform: scale(.8, .8);
    -o-transform: scale(.8, .8);
    -ms-transform: scale(.8, .8);
    transform: scale(.8,.8);
}
```

This is very basic CSS. Also, I have no idea what you mean with `have options for what I can do on a hover state`.

Comment: I appreciate the response but if you dont want to answer, please don't. Your appendage of 'This is very basic CSS' is not necessary.